getting gulp error while running testcase in intellij idea
How do I resolve gulp error Trying to run test on public class in intelliJ idea. First I saw error                             'error: command failed: git config --get remote.origin.url'
I ran below command:
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
Now seeing gulp error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import [INFO]     at createScript (vm.js:56:10) [INFO]     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10) [INFO]     at Module._compile (module.js:549:28) [INFO]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10) [INFO]     at Module.load (module.js:494:32) [INFO]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12) [INFO]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3) [INFO]     at Module.require (module.js:504:17) [INFO]     at require (internal/module.js:20:19) [INFO]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/git/xxxx/xxxxx/gulpfile.js:3:13)

What does your gulpfile look like, what command do you use to run it?
